# How can I restore default GRUB looks?

Tags: 12.04, grub2

Recently I'm installed Ubuntu 12.04. When I boot I have the option to boot two systems: Windows 7 and Ubuntu.

After installing Ubuntu connecting net then its show new updates. I updated Ubuntu. Then after updating my PC asked to restart. I restarted the PC, but now in GRUB's background changed, it shows something about Dedian Universal Operating System displayed and one globe symbol wallpaper is displayed.

How to change that wallpaper into default Ubuntu wallpaper?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you've managed to install the default grub wallpaper for Debian!

Anyway, there are instructions [here](http://members.iinet.net/~herman546/p20/GRUB2%20Splashimages.html) for changing the wallpaper to anything you like, but I don't know where you'd find the 'default' Ubuntu wallpaper for grub.

The basic idea is to define 3 environment variables similar to the following:

```
WALLPAPER=/usr/share/images/desktop-base/desktop-grub.png
COLOR_NORMAL=light-gray/black
COLOR_HIGHLIGHT=white/black
```

WALLPAPER names an image file to use as a background, and the other 2 define the menu colors. (`/etc/default/grub' is probably a good place to put them)